# Is there a need for a new field of natural-practical philosophy?

Tags: political-philosophy, physics, quantum-physics, practical-ethics, natural-philosophy

Natural philosophy is now generally known as physics. Some ancient universities still call it natural philosophy. But all of science could be included under the term, natural philosophy. There is also a division in modern philosophy between theoretical philosophy and practical philosophy. Practical ethics and political philosophy are examples of practical philosophy. Some philosophical questions refer to the philosophical implications of quantum events. Is there a role in the modern world for a new field of natural-practical philosophy to consider these particular questions taking into account scientific evidence?

Comment: Social science? Political science, sociology etc? Sociology often gets deliberately mixed up with philosophy.